# in haskell, why do I need to specify type constraints, why can't the compiler figure them out?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass, type-systems

Consider the function,

```
add a b = a + b
```

This works:

```
*Main> add 1 2
3
```

However, if I add a type signature specifying that I want to add things of the same type:

```
add :: a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b
```

I get an error:

```
test.hs:3:10:
    Could not deduce (Num a) from the context ()
      arising from a use of `+' at test.hs:3:10-14
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of the type signature for `add'
    In the expression: a + b
    In the definition of `add': add a b = a + b
```

So GHC clearly *can* deduce that I need the `Num` type constraint, since it just told me:

```
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b
```

Works.

Why does GHC require me to add the type constraint?  If I'm doing generic programming, why can't it just work for anything that knows how to use the `+` operator?

In C++ template programming, you can do this easily:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T add(T a, T b) { return a + b; }

int main()
{
    printf("%d, %f, %s\n",
           add(1, 2),
           add(1.0, 3.4),
           add(string("foo"), string("bar")).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler figures out the types of the arguments to `add` and generates a version of the function for that type.  There seems to be a fundamental difference in Haskell's approach, can you describe it, and discuss the trade-offs?  It seems to me like it would be resolved if GHC simply filled in the type constraint for me, since it obviously decided it was needed.  Still, why the type constraint at all?  Why not just compile successfully as long as the function is only used in a valid context where the arguments are in `Num`?

Comment: Why should it magically turn the type signature into something much less general by adding a constraint *when you explicitly told it you want no constraints* (by declaring `add :: a -> a -> a`)? Also note that in Haskell, there is no thing that has `(+)` overloaded but isn't an instance of `Num` (because `(+)` is in `Num`, so to overload it you have to declare a `Num` instance).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to specify the function's type, just leave it out and the compiler will infer the types automatically. But if you choose to specify the types, they *have* to be correct and accurate.

Comment: I think you hit the nail here. If you want to specify the type, then you don't want the compiler to ignore your specification (or "correct" it)

Answer (score 15):

The *entire point* of types is to have a formal way to declare the right and wrong way to use a function. A type of `(Num a) => a -> a -> a` describes exactly what is required of the arguments. If you omitted the class constraint, you would have a more general function that could be used (erroneously) in more places.

And it’s not just preventing you from passing non-`Num` values to `add`. Everywhere the function goes, the type is sure to go. Consider this:

```
add :: a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b
foo :: [a -> a -> a]
foo = [add]
value :: [String]
value = [f "hello" "world" | f <- foo]
```

You want the compiler to reject this, right? How does it do that? By adding class constraints, and checking that they are not removed, even if you don’t directly name the function.

What’s different in the C++ version? There are no class constraints. The compiler substitutes `int` or `std::string` for `T`, then tries to compile the resulting code and looks for a matching `+` operator that it can use. The template system is “looser”, since it accepts more invalid programs, and this is a symptom of it being a separate stage before compilation. I would *love* to modify C++ to add the `<? extends T>` semantics from Java’s generics. Just learn the type system and recognize that parametric polymorphism is “stronger” than C++ templates, namely it will reject more invalid programs.

Comment: I still don't see why the compiler couldn't deduce the restriction to add in the 2nd line, propagate it to foo in the 4th line and detect an error in the 6th line. It may not be very useful, but technically possible, right?

Comment: @adamax: Yes, it is technically possible, but then how do I actually assert to the compiler that a function has the unconstrained type `a -> a -> a`?  This is a perfectly meaningful type all on its own, and if I tell the compiler that my function has such a type, I really don't want it silently saying to itself "OK, he said "a -> a -> a", but I know he actually meant Foo a => a -> a -> a".  If it's saying that to itself, I want it to tell me that I was wrong, because I _was_.

Comment: mokus: your comment here is more convincing than any of the answers.  "If it's saying that to itself, I want it to tell me that I was wrong, because I was."  Thanks, that really makes it clear.

Answer (score 12):

I think you might be being tripped up by the "crazy moon poetry" of GHC's error messages.  It's not saying that *it* (being GHC) couldn't deduce the `(Num a)` constraint. It is saying that the `(Num a)` constraint can't be deduced from *your* type signature, which it knows must be there from the use of `+`. Hence, you're are stating that this function has a type more general than the compiler knows it can have. The compiler doesn't want you lying about your functions to the world!

In the first example you gave, without the type signature, if you run `:t add` in ghci, you'll see that the compiler knows full well that the `(Num a)` constraint is there.

As for C++'s templates, remember that they are syntactic templates and are only fully type checked in each instance as they are used. Your `add` template will work with any types so long as, at each place it is used, there is a suitable `+` operator and perhaps conversions, to make an instance of the template viable. No guarantees can be made about the template until then... which is why the body of the template must be "visible" to each module that uses it.

Basically, all C++ can do is validate the syntax of the template, and then keep it around as a kind of very hygienic macro. Whereas Haskell generates a real function for `add` (leaving aside that it may choose to also generate type specific specializations for optimization).

Answer (score 2):

There are cases where the compiler **can't** figure out the right type for you and where it needs your help. Consider

```
f s = show $ read s
```

The compiler says:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
Read a' arising from a use of `read' at src\Main.hs:20:13-18
`Show a' arising from a use of `show' at src\Main.hs:20:6-9
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

(Strange enough, it seems you can define this function in ghci, but it seems there is no way to actually use it)

If you want that something like `f "1"` works, you **need** to specify the type:

```
f s = show $ (read s :: Int)
```

Comment: GHCi uses looser "defaulting" rules than the Haskell standard officially specifies.  In this case, it will choose `read :: String -> ()`, so you can use `f` on the string "()".  Any other string will fail to parse.  (Edit:  well, except for other strings that the () instance of read accepts, such as "()   ")

Comment: since ghc version 8 one can use `TypeApplications` to annotate a function like `read . show @Int`, which allows one to write the function `f` above pointfree.